# Every entity need to be so big in QGIS main display to fit big layout printer

Tags: qgis, layers, layouts

In QGIS I am organising layer to print a map in tabloid format. I need to set my entities in a very big size for them to fit in the printer. Is there a way to just make match the format of the printer and the format of the main viewer? In ARCGIS it seems to adapt to the printer format that is defined.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried tried changing the unit type in the styling?
By Default it is usually millimeter but changing to pixel/point will make it more print accurate.

Comment: It solve the problem, thank you! Is there a way to make it default in my project?

Comment: Yes, please see the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the unit type in the styling will fix the issue.
By default it is usually **'millimeter'** but changing to **'pixel'** or **'point'** will make it more print accurate.

The default units can be set via **Project Properties > Default Styles**.

[image: Change Units]

[image: Default Style]